# Images from API not getting displayed in flutter application

Tags: flutter, api

I wanted to display images from Unsplash API in my flutter application. I followed steps from a youtube tutorial, the code ran without any errors but the images are not getting displayed in the application.

I have attached the code below (<api_access_key> contained the access key for the unsplash API.)

I expect the output to be a list of images from the Unsplash API. The code is done in Android Studio.

I'm new to APIs and would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class wpList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _wpListState createState() => _wpListState();
}

class _wpListState extends State<wpList> {


  List data = [];
  List<String> wpUrl=[];
  bool showing = false;

  getData() async{
    http.Response response= await http.get(Uri.parse('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=<api_access_key>'));
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    _assign();
    setState(() {
      showing = true;
    });
  }

  _assign(){
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      wpUrl.add(data.elementAt(1)["urls"]["regular"]);
      print(wpUrl);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  //height: 50,
                  //color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Container(
                    child: !showing? CircularProgressIndicator():Image(image: NetworkImage(wpUrl.elementAt(index))),
                  )
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

`

[This is the output that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKk8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called the function to get the data

API calls usually are done from `initState` ([more about initState](https://flutteragency.com/what-is-initstate-and-super-initstate-in-flutter/))
Try adding this above your `build` method

```
@override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer! Now I'm getting some renderBox error, but I think I'll be able to fix that. Thanks again!

Comment: @kkridhi I think you can ask new question while it is layout issue. Make sure to include a minimal snippet showing your effort to overcome the issue.

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh thanks for the suggestion, but I have fixed the error by myself, so no problem!

Answer (score 2):

you have written code well to show the data assuming that you already have initial data. But you don't have any initial data. When the code runs, `data = []` is an empty list, and `data.length` in the ListView builder does not show any data.

We should call `getData()` before rendering the ui(we should populate data array before rendering the ui). We can do this by calling `getData()` from init function as below.

```
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

But there is a **small chance that images do get displayed in this case also**.

**Reason:**

your getData() method runs in an asynchronous thread as it is an async function. So, `getData()` code gets into the asynchronous thread for execution. But the control doesn't wait for the completion of `getData()` and skips to the next line (in this case build method).

So your images get displayed only if the network request in the `getData()` method does not take too much time so that data gets initialized before the control reaches the build method.

**Fix**

1. You can initialize data inside setState(){} so that rendering takes place once again when data is initialized
2. you can call await method inside **initState()** so that control waits until the complete execution of **getData()** function. But you get error in this case that we can not add async modifier to init function which can be solved using below reference.
   https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/63/how-to-run-async-await-code-in-initstate-flutter-app/

**Please upvote and accept the answer if useful**

Comment: Thanks for answering! I got the output that I needed!